# Call to undefined function blenc_encrypt()

Tags: php

недавно узнал про такую вещь как blenc_encrypt, и => я полез в документацию, и следовал по примеру:

```php
<?php

/* Читаем исходный скрипт PHP */
$source_code = file_get_contents("my_source_to_protect.php");

/* Шифруем */
$redistributable_key = blenc_encrypt($source_code, "my_source_encoded.php");

/* Выясняем, где расположен файл ключа */
$key_file = ini_get('blenc.key_file');

/* Сохраняем распространяемый ключ */
file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Но такая ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function blenc_encrypt()
```

Версия PHP 7.0.3, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Помимо примера в документации еще есть пара глав, которые стоило бы прочесть. Например, ту в которой написано "Это расширение PECL не поставляется вместе с PHP. "

Comment: @u_mulder Получается его не реализовать на хостинге?

Comment: Ну если только пересобрать php с этим расширением, как предлагают в мануале. А так наверно нет, это же небезопасно, наворочаешь в рантайме и хостера вопросами забросаешь. Ему это надо?)

Comment: @u_mulder Тогда не можешь посоветовать, как сделать нормальную защиту скрипта? Md5 хеш домена - это ключ, и сделать множество проверок, чтобы скрипт работал только на этом домене. Кратко - лицензирование.